# How to check alert dialog item selected or not?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I set alert dialog on textview,where I used String array,now how to check none of the item is selected or not,if none of item selected it should not submit..check my snippet code below..thanks in advance..

```
  sp3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.daydates);
  btnsubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnreg);

 final String[] items = new String[] {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter123 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);


    sp3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View w) {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(RegistrationForm.this)
              .setTitle("Select Day")
              .setAdapter(adapter123, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    sp3.setText(adapter123.getItem(which).toString());

                  dialog.dismiss();
                }
              }).create().show();
            }
    });
   btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
     {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(emailtext.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && passtext.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && confirmpass.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && username.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && firstname.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && lastname.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && isSetDay==true && isSetMonth==true && isSetYear==true && isSetPro==true)
        {
            isSetDay=false;
            isSetMonth=false;
            isSetYear=false;
            isSetPro=false;
        new AttemptLogin().execute();

        final String uname=username.getText().toString();
        if(!isValidUserName(uname))
        {
            username.setError("Invalid User Name");
        }
        final String fname=firstname.getText().toString();
        if(!isValidFirstName(fname))
        {
            firstname.setError("Invalid First Name");
        }
        final String lname=lastname.getText().toString();
        if(!isValidLastName(lname))
        {
            lastname.setError("Invalid Last Name");
        }

        }

        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill the details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        break;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use a boolean to determine if sp3 has been set when btnsubmit is clicked then reset it if you need to re-use it.

This is my suggestion:

```
 sp3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.daydates);
 btnsubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnreg);
 boolean isSet = false;

 final String[] items = new String[] {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter123 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);


    sp3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View w) {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(RegistrationForm.this)
              .setTitle("Select Day")
              .setAdapter(adapter123, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    sp3.setText(adapter123.getItem(which).toString());
                    isSet = true;

                  dialog.dismiss();
                }
              }).create().show();
            }
    });

     btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
     {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(!isSet)
            {
                //Do Something
                isSet = false;
            }
        }
    });
```